# is there way to set timestamp in unbounded source pcollection?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

i want to set timestamp to the unbounded pcollection of strings

in my solution each line of the pcollection is a row of csv

in one field of this row have a timestamp and others fields like number of clicks etc.

i want to process the collection with base on its own timestamp (event time )not the default timestamp that set apache beam

the main threat of this dataflow is group the number of clicks per minute

i have a ftp service that send files to one folder that my job listen each 1 min and process in fix window of 1 min 
the problem is that is possible arrive late data

i do KV pcolection and key is the timestamp without seconds and value num of clicks and apply group by

i get "clicks per minute" and i send this pcollection to database

example 
package of data element generate to 12:05pm (10 files)
time recive the data 12:06pm

Job generation data
12:05pm 120 clicks

package of data element generate to 12:05pm  and 12:06 (files late of 12:05)

time receive the data 12:07pm

Job generation data 
12:05pm 10 clicks
12:06pm 135 clicks

i want discard the process of the late data based in event data 
is possible in the way that i am search

in other words dont put in db the late data -> 12:05pm  -10clicks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WithTimestamps](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/WithTimestamps.html) transform to assign timestamps from the data. For example, assuming your key is a string that can be parsed by [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html):

```
records.apply(
 WithTimestamps.of((KV<String, String> rec) -> Instant.parse(rec.getKey()));
```